# Angular 9 new YouTube Player component - how to jump to the new startSeconds

Tags: javascript, angular, youtube, angular9

With Angular 9 the [Components library](https://github.com/angular/components/) have this [new YouTube Player control](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/youtube-player/youtube-player.ts). The [readme file](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/youtube-player/README.md) contains the simple example of use.

All I want to change is buttons setting starting playback time.

```
  <youtube-player
    [startSeconds]="startSecondsNumber"
    [videoId]="videoId"
  ></youtube-player>
```

I bind the startSeconds and videoId properties. What I expected was: each time `startSecondsNumber` changes, the playback will jump to the new timestamp. What I observe instead is as follows.

If I reload the page, click on a button that changes `startSecondsNumber` and click play on the YouTube control, the playback starts from the right timestamp.

Whatever I button I click next,setting `startSecondsNumber`, the playback continues. 
Even when I pause (by clicking on the widget's pause control), the clicks changing the `startSecondsNumber` value seem to have no effect.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to reset the playback, or pause it, or start playing again?